# Reverse a dictionary using single "for" loop or using "itertools" library

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

I have a dictionary of lists like this:

```
my_dict = {
    'key_a': [1, 3, 4],
    'key_b': [0, 2],
}
```

I want to create a reverse lookup dict like this:

```
reverse_dict = {
    0: 'key_b',
    1: 'key_a',
    2: 'key_b',
    3: 'key_a',
    4: 'key_a',
}
```

I have a **working version of the solution**:

```
reverse_dict = {elem: key for key, a_list in my_dict.items() for elem in a_list}
```

But wanted to know if someone can provide an alternate answer that doesn't use a double `for` as I feel it loses readability. So I'd prefer having a single `for` loop or use functions like the ones in itertools or functional programming

Comment: what about duplicate keys? last key in wins?

Comment: Your code looks perfect to this pair of eyes.

Comment: we can assume lists won't have duplicate elements

Comment: This *is* functional programming.

Comment: The code you have is the pythonic way to achieve it, and it is very simple as compared to various nested single liners that you may write in Python. I don't see any issue with readability here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution using *dictionary comprehension* is the Pythonic way to achieve it.

However, as an **alternative with single `for` loop** as requested by you, here is the functional one using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), [`itertools.repeat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat), and [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), but I doubt that it is any better then yours solution in terms of readability:

```
my_dict = {
    'key_a': [1, 3, 4],
    'key_b': [0, 2],
}

from itertools import chain, repeat

new_dict = dict(chain.from_iterable(zip(v, repeat(k)) for k, v in my_dict.items()))
```

where `new_dict` will hold:

```
{0: 'key_b', 1: 'key_a', 2: 'key_b', 3: 'key_a', 4: 'key_a'}
```

Comment: It's clear from the comments and the received answers that readability is not an issue with my code. I don't want to delete my question as it might be useful for someone else. I'll accept this answer as it shows the best use of itertools as requested

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> dict(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda k: map(lambda j:(j, k), my_dict.get(k)), my_dict)))
{1: 'key_a', 3: 'key_a', 4: 'key_a', 0: 'key_b', 2: 'key_b'}
```

No for loops. It's clearly not more readable

Another one based off @MoinuddinQuadri's idea

```
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat
>>> dict(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda k: zip(my_dict[k], repeat(k)), my_dict)))
{1: 'key_a', 3: 'key_a', 4: 'key_a', 0: 'key_b', 2: 'key_b'}
```

Comment: very unwanted usage of lambdas with `map` to remove `for` loops. But still "+1" as OP only wants to reduce them

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, it is a silly question, but it can be fun to kick these ideas around and see what drops out

Answer (score 1):

Here's one without explicit for loop. Not really recommended, though (side-effect in `map` which is a no-no to many):

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> out = {}
>>> any(map(out.update, it.starmap(dict.fromkeys, map(reversed, my_dict.items()))))
False
>>> out
{1: 'key_a', 3: 'key_a', 4: 'key_a', 0: 'key_b', 2: 'key_b'}
```

Comment: Side effect in map is indeed a no-no, so just a +0.7 rounded up